# Android Studio - Layout Editor All Blured

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I tired both "is.hidpi=false" and "hidpi=false". The first one doesn't fix it. The second one does, but it makes all other icons in Android Studio way too small for my display(23.8 inch 1440p monitor), so I can't really work well in any scenario. Do you have any suggestions?

[image: Blurred Layout Preview]

Comment: Hi @emre, as a suggestion you may want to add an image here to your post so that it may get easier for people to help you as it's a layout related question.

Comment: I added an image.

Comment: Thanks. Does it happen on every phone types? e.g.: if you change it from Pixel and api 28 to other configurations you still see this error? Have you tried to refresh your layout editor? There's a button for it on that same editor. It could maybe be also some error on your xml layout itself? Maybe check if there's any warnings appearing?

Comment: I've tried all the api levels. Layout refresh is not working. The problem seems to be in android studio settings. This is the problem that comes with the latest updates. When I do hidpi=false, it improves. Everything on the screen is getting smaller.

Comment: Ah, okay. I see. Thanks for the details. Sorry don't know the answer at this point myself but hopefully someone will read your post and will be able to help you a bit more than me.